# No mobs are spawning in my mob farm

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have a mob farm but for some reason no mobs are spawning. I've looked at many tutorials and none of them have helped/worked. Here's a screenshot:
Extra info: I'm on a server, 0 players online except me
[image: Image of farm]

[[image: image2i]

Comment: Have you tried leaving the chunks and coming back? Whenever I build a mob farm, they seem to need a reload like this before they start working.

Answer (score 1):

There are several reasons why mobs may not spawn in a farm.

- Mob spawning is set to false in the settings.
- You are the wrong distance from the point you want the mobs to spawn.
- The light level is too high (though judging from your screenshot this is not the case).
- The mobs are spawning elsewhere.
- There is not enough space for them to spawn / there are carpet or slabs preventing spawning (but again, not likely based on given info).

There is also a possibility that the tutorial you watched was meant for Bedrock Edition.

If you would like me to improve this answer I would need a screenshot of this farm during the day and possible the video you based it off of.

Comment: This is the tutorial I used: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AYeh6T3czlU
Mob spawning is enabled. I have tested possible ranges that the mobs could spawn and none  of which they spawned

Comment: Updated the post!

Comment: I skimmed through the tutorial. I play on Bedrock Edition, not Java, so I can't say much as to whether or not it works (though it looks fine). The only possible problem I can think of at this point is that it is possible your slabs are not oriented as the video instructs. Mobs cannot spawn on slabs that cover only the bottom half of a block. They *can* spawn if it covers the top half of the block. Other than that I do not know, sorry.